# Cambiar formato de YY-MM-DD a DD-MM-YY sql

Tags: javascript, php, sql

La base de datos la realice en phpmyadmin, en la misma tabla se ingresa la fecha mediante date y otros campos que me piden. Los mando a llamar en php para a su vez generar un reporte en fpfp. Me piden que el formato de la fecha este en DD-MM-YY. Tienen algún consejo, alguna sentencia que me pueda ayudar, ya sea de sql,php o js. muchas gracias -_-

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: NUNCA guardes fechas en otro formato que no sea YYYY-MM-DD. Si los necesitas en otro formato, solo le dices a MySQL que te los devuelva como quieres con [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Y si estás trabajando con aplicaciones internacionales, te ahorrarás millones de dolores de cabeza tan solo con guardar las fechas con el formato  [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html). Por ejemplo: '2021-11-22T14:36:40.370Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Date_Format puedes formatear las fechas de una tabla como tu quieras.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y');
```

Hos dejo un link de w3school para que veas los diferente parametros que puede tener esta funcion.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$consulta = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') AS date FROM asesoria"
```

Comment: Tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor si das una pequeña explicación de como resuelve el problema de OP, recuerda que no todos los usuarios tienen el mismo nivel como para comprender tu código a la primera. ;)